# Why is there no windbg in latest version of wdk?

Tags: windbg, wdk

I just installed `wdk 7600.16385.1`(from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487463)) ,

and find **windbg** is missing even though I've chosen to install all components.

Is it officially removed from wdk now?

If that's the case,why?

Answer (score 1):

WinDbg is shipped as a part of the Windows SDK. Please, check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463016.aspx. Install latest Windows SDK, and WinDbg can be found in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Redist\Debugging Tools for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was somehow installed in the directory C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)

Answer (score 0):

It's contained in my (installed) copy of this exact WDK build (`C:\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\Debuggers\windbg.exe`). So no idea why it wouldn't be in yours.

Also, to my knowledge WinDbg was moved *into* the WDKs (and SDKs), with newer versions not being available through other channels, rather than out of them.